# Print 1 item from returned tuple or list data

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am fairly new to python and am working on a project that uses rest protocol to retrieve data from a device(robot). I am trying to break the data down from a huge list so that I can get a specific value out of it. Here is my code:

```
getMissionQueue = robot.get_mission_queue()[1][0]
    print(getMissionQueue)
```

At this point, "getMissionQueue" will print

> {u'state': u'Executing', u'id': 1286}

The value that I am trying to get as a stand alone variable is 1286. I tried doing this but it is only returning string values:

```
for item in getMissionQueue:
        print (item)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `getMissionQueue` is a `dict`, so use `getMissionQueue[u'id']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find what you're looking for with `getMissionQueue['id']`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294899/5359735) explains the issue with your for loop!

Comment: Your suggestion worked beautifully! And thank you for the link with more information as well. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For python 2 you can use .iteritems() to iterate over a dictionary:

```
d = {u'state': u'Executing', u'id': 1286}
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

In python 3 use .items():

```
d = {u'state': u'Executing', u'id': 1286}
    for k, v in d.items():
        print k,v
```

Answer (score -1):

You call parts of a tuple by using the tuple name, then a number (starting from zero. So for example:

```
print(getmissionQueue[0])
```

will print the first item in the tuple.

```
print(getmisionQueue[1])
```

will print the second item in the queue.

Comment: This returned a KeyError on mine. I think I made a mistake and it was actually a dictionary so this didn't work like it would with a tuple. Cheers